# Custom Delegate For UICollectionView Cell - Custom Button Not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom cell Subclassed from UIcollectionViewCell . Through code i have created buttons and added to the cell with target method in the same class.

button event is working fine . But i need to take control to my base view where i created UICollectionView.

So for that i have created custom delegate for recognizing the tap event.

---> DBDraggingCell.h file

```
@protocol DBDraggingCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)chartButtonpressed:(id)sender;
-(void)accountHistoryButtonpressed:(id)sender;
-(void)transactionHistoryButtonpressed:(id)sender;
@end

@interface DBDraggingCell : UICollectionViewCell{

    UIButton *chartButton;
    UIButton *accSummaryButton;
    UIButton *transactionHistory;

}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////

```
-(void)chartPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

    [_delegate chartButtonpressed:sender];

}

_delegate returns nil

----> In baseview i have set the delegate 

[self addSubview:_theCollectionView];
_theCollectionView.delegate=self;


Not working


The methods inside the baseview not called
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you didn't set cell delegate in your collectionView

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DBDraggingCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:DBDraggingCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.delegate = self;

    ....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your base view is UICollectionView instance, isn't it?
If your base view is UICollectionView, you have to set DBDraggingCell's delegate in the loading cells method `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

For Example:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        DBDraggingCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Set DBDraggingCell' delegate here
        cell.delegate = self;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your delegate property corresponds to the variable _delegate, which you used when you perform the delegate method. It is better to use the property everywhere that could helps you to avoid those kind of issues.